# How can I use React powerplug's hover to add and remove a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If hovered I want to add the class 'first-time' to bgFeatureImage
When the mouse leave/ not hovered I want to remove that class

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Hover } from 'react-powerplug';

<Hover onChange={()=>{test : test2('first-time')}}>
     {({ hovered, bind }) => (
          <li>
            <a href="/"
               {...bind}>
                First time
            </a>
          </li>
   )}
</Hover>

export const test = link => {
 const bgFeatureImage = document.getElementById('bg-feature-image').classList.add(link) ;
 console.log('hover');
};
export const test2 = link => {
const bgFeatureImage = document.getElementById('bg-feature-image').classList.remove(link) ;
console.log('not hover');
};
```

I'm very new to JavaScript and React and don't understand the documention.
Can you please explain like I'm 5 why this doesn't work and how to use it?

Comment: do you really need to use powerplug? or is it ok to add/remove class onhover without using that package?

Comment: I've been told to use powerplug but I don't understand how to use it unfortunately @Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

please check this code:

Have handled the hover/hover-out conditions. you can now manipulate the hoverHandler

[image: Edit jpnj21l495]

https://jpnj21l495.codesandbox.io/

Comment: read more about react components here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-your-first-react-js-component-d728d759cabc